# Call custom URI Scheme (eg lightroom://myplugin... ) from shell / terminal / AppleScript instead of web browser on OS X

Tags: macos, shell, curl, applescript, lightroom

Adobe Lightroom uses its own URI scheme: lightroom://myplugin.details/command to send messages to installed plugins.

I'm trying to trigger these from OS X (specifically from AppleScript in my case). I can do this by telling Safari or Firefox to open the url "lightroom://...." which works. However, I'm sending hundreds of these commands and the tabs are getting unmanageable.

It would be much better to send this in the background, eg via a shell script or curl, but curl does not understand lightroom:// links, and so I'm not sure how do to this.

I don't need to get any response back, just trigger the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard Additions in AppleScript contains the command

> **open location** (*verb*): Opens a URL with the appropriate program (from Internet Suite, defined in StandardAdditions.osax)

for example

```
open location "lightroom://myplugin.details/command"
```

without any application tell block.

Comment: So simple! Brilliant - thanks so much. Will award the bounty as soon as it lets me.